# How to handle errors when user denies authorization to Discord OAuth2 application with passport-discord?

Tags: authentication, nestjs, passport.js

I'm currently building an API with Nest using the Discord strategy from PassportJS. Everything works as expected, when the user grants authorization for my Discord application i can access the "identify" scope of that account.

However, I've encountered an issue: when the user denies authorization, the `/redirect` endpoint returns the following JSON response:

```json
{"message":"Unauthorized","statusCode":401}
```

I've searched a lot, but haven't found a way to handle this error. The version information for the PassportJS library is ^0.6.0 and for the Discord strategy is ^0.1.4.

Here's a snippet of my /redirect endpoint code:

```js
@UseGuards(UnifiedAuthGuard)
@Get('discord/redirect')
async discordRedirect(@Req() req: Request) {
   // only reaches here if it's authorized

   // returns the req.user as a response to the original window and closes the /redirect
   return `
  <script>
   window.opener.postMessage(${JSON.stringify(
     req.user,
   )}, "http://localhost:4200/login");
   window.close();
  </script>`;
}
```

Is there a recommended way to handle this specific error when the user denies authorization in the Discord strategy of PassportJS? My goal is to handle the denial by providing a user-friendly message, preventing the display of the "Unauthorized" error at /redirect.

I tried the following code inside my /redirect endpoint to check if there was an error:

```js
if (req.query.error) {
  console.log('unauthorized');
  return `
  <script>
    window.opener.postMessage({ error: "${req.query.error_description}" }, "http://localhost:4200/login");
    window.close();
  </script>
`;
```

However, it never reaches this point, it doesn't even log 'unauthorized'. When the user denies authorization, the application redirects to /discord/redirect, but the page remains open, displaying the previously mentioned error.